# Two-fold cross validation using optimal parameters in Python

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I want to train an SVM classifier using two-fold cross validation with optimal parameters with GridSearchCV. Till far i have done something like this following the documentation but it seems wrong. I have two lists with the data and the labels where each element of each list is an  array containing the data and the labels respectively:

```
import sklearn
kf_total = cross_validation.KFold(len(data), n_folds=2, indices=True, shuffle=False, random_state=4)
C = SVC()
[C.fit(data[train_indices], labels[train_indices]).score(data[test_indices],labels[test_indices])
for train_indices, test_indices in kf_total]

len(data) = 4300
data[0] = array([[1, 2, 3],
                 [4, 5, 6],
                 [7, 8, 9],
             ...,
                 [1, 2, 3],
                 [4, 5, 6],
                 [7, 8, 9],  

label[0] = 1
label[1] = 2 . . . . label[4299] = 60
```

Is that correct? How can i tune it with the optimal parameters using GridSearchCV?